# Convert dataset into list row is taking much time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

i am calculating TFIDF, for that i need to convert my data set into list row.

My dataset has 40,00,000 records, when i call collectAsList function for my dataset it is taking more than 20mins to complete.
My RAM configured of 16gb.

Basically i need to work on individual row to calculate TFIDF for that particular record.

Please suggest me is there any other type of function to convert data set into list row in spark.

Even i tried for and foreach loop also, but still it is taking time.

Below is my sample code.

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("connection example").getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> tokenlist= sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("nullValue", "").load("D:\\AI_MATCHING\\exampleTFIDF.csv");
tokenlist= tokenlist.select("features");
tokenlist.show(false);
List<Row> tokenizedWordsList1 = tokenlist.collectAsList();

/*tokenlist.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) individaulRow -> {


    newtest.ItemIDSourceIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("ItemIDSource");
    newtest.upcSourceIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("upcSource");
    newtest.ManufacturerSourceIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("ManufacturerSource");
    newtest.ManufacturerPartNumberSourceIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("Manufacturer part NumberSource");
    newtest.PART_NUMBER_SOURCEIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("PART_NUMBER_SOURCE");
    newtest.productDescriptionSourceIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("productDescriptionSource");
    newtest.HASH_CODE_dummyIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("HASH_CODE_dummy");
    newtest.rowIdSourceIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("rowIdSource");
    newtest.rawFeaturesIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("rawfeatures                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ");
    newtest.featuresIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("features                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ");

    });*/
```

Comment: Spark already implements TF-IDF, why not use it? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#tf-idf

Comment: After TFIDF calculation i need to take individual row and assign that values.

Comment: What do you need to assign? Use the provided `fit`/`transform` methods and set an output column.

Comment: Basically i need to find the matching between 2 records, so i need to assign the TFIDF values. i need output column in the form of list not in the dataset form

Answer (score 0):

A) Spark ML library already doing TFIDF calculations by itself, try to use those methods.

B) If you have large rows (toList() will take time), try to use SQL methods.
Such as convert dataset into a table and query on it with certain conditions

Comment: A) i am calculating TFIDF using Spark ML library only.


B) i need convert data set row into list row and assign those values to find the matching between 2 records.